# icingaweb2 not reachable on apache

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, icinga2

the icingaweb2 is not reachable, although it is running on the server with the apache and icinga2. I already have all the prerequisites, that are documented on the official site set up. However, when accessing the icingaweb2 site on apache (https://hostname/icingaweb2/setup) I get a 404 server error

the link (https://hostname/) works and shows the **default site of apache**

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

apache virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html


                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key





                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>


        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you follow the icinga2 and icingaweb2 installation documentation? What commands did you enter to setup icingaweb2?

Comment: @wazoox I followed the following steps:

1. apt install icingaweb2
2. apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1
3. setup mysqldb:
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP VIEW, INDEX, EXECUTE ON icinga2.* TO 'icingaweb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY password;
4. icingacli setup config directory --group icingaweb2;
5. icingacli setup token create;

Comment: What's in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled ? What's in /var/www/html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A downgrade from php8.1 to php7.4 helped